# Laravel: datepicker is not working

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need a help. `datepicker` is not working on laravel view file please help how to make it working

For Live file, I have used this:

```
{!! Html::script('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css') !!}
{!! Html::script('https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js') !!}

<style>
    col-sm-2 control-label{
        text-align: left !important;
    }
</style>
```

and on input box I put id="datepicker"

Comment: Tried `$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to put `class="datepicker"` in your input like this:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker">
```

And you need to add some script as:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

This is whole HTML page with necessary files.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Jquery - Datepicker Example using jquery ui</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">   

</head>

<body>


<div class="container text-center">

     <h2>Jquery - Datepicker Example using jquery ui</h2>

     <strong>Select Date:</strong> <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="from-control">

</div>  


<script type="text/javascript">

    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: I've added some lines of datepicker code please try.

Comment: After all I don't know what's the problem, In same case in mine it had worked

Comment: You should inspect the element and then there might be some problem with js look at console at once

Comment: @eliana I've added whole `html` file take a moment to view it.

Comment: There should be some syntax error at some line due to space between $ and ( ) so see line where error occurred. or some where you have placed $ only.

Comment: $('.date').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        todayBtn: "linked",
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true
    });

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code in your app.blade.php

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

After that add `date` as your input type in the blade.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob">
```